# Why is process.env returning an empty object, while process.env.prop returns the prop value?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

So I have the simplest example on a node machine running with a react-redux app with webpack (Though I don't think any of this matters for the issue expect it being on nodejs).

Specific calls get a value pack:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // output: 'development'
```

General calls get nothing back:

```
console.log(process.env); // output: {}
```

What am I missing here?

Addition info the *might* be relevant:

- I am using `dotenv` for the `test` environment.
- I am using `dotenv-webpack` for the development environment.
- I am not using neither of those for the `production` environment deployed to Heroku
- The problem persists on all environments.

Comment: These console logs are one next the other? Are placed within a test? With which command do you run the js file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue with `process.env` variable being empty in browser is because browser doesn't have real access to the `process` of the `node.js`. It's run inside the browser though.

Usage of `process.env.ANYTHING` is usually achieved by plugins like https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/ which just simply `replace` any occurrence of `process.env.ANYTINHG` with env variable during BUILD time. It really does just simple `str.replace(/process.env.ANYTING/value/)` this needs to be done during build time as once you output dist `bundle.js` you don't have access to the `ENV` variables.

## Replacing during build time

Therefore you need to be sure that when you are producing production build e.g with `yarn build` you are using `webpack.DefinePlugin` and replacing those `process.env` calls with current ENV values. They can't be injected in runtime.

## Injecting in runtime

When you need to access env variables in runtime it's basically impossible in JavaScript in browser. There are some sort of hacks for example for NGINX which can serialize current env variables to the `window.ENV` variable and in your app you will not use `process.env` but `window.ENV`. So you need to either have ENV variables available while you are building the application or build mechanism which will dynamically output current ENV as json to window and access with react. If you are using `docker` it can be done with `ENTRYPOINT` otherwise you need some bash script which will always output current ENV variables as `JSON` to the `index.html` of your app

Comment: Hey thanks, i did figure it out on my own eventually and have set up the webpack.DefinePlugin (btw it is mildly infuriating the some web-pack plugins require installation and some don't). So it works now, but it's so inelegant, the whole fun of the `.env` files is that they bring some order to it while defining it via webpack manually doesn't sit well.. but that's just extra. Thanks for the help and clear answer!

Comment: here is the link to the webpack docs on define plugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/